# Customize Magento country?

Tags: php, html, magento, show, country

I'm developing ecommerece site using magento.
My problem is,

- Show all countries dropdown box in user register page.
- But show only india,singapore,usa in dropdown box in product shipping address for registerd user and guest.

Anybody help to solve this problem.
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shipping can be allowed only to defined countries. It can be set in shipping method settings (**system->configuration->shipping methods->your shipping method->Ship to Applicable Countries**). There are couple of values: "Ship to Applicable Countries" and "Specific Countries". If you set up second value, shipping will be aviable only to that countries, that you will select in the feald below.